# Issues with my WiFi accessing just GitHub

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, dns, wifi-configuration, github

This happened randomly but I can't get access to GitHub. I tried using the app on my phone and logging in through my browser, through my iPad, etc. Nothing works.

I've tried pushing changes via GitKraken but I can't really verify if it is on GitHub either. Every other site works on all my devices and only GitHub does not work, so I am not sure what the issue is.

I use AT&T. The only other thing I noticed was an issue is that I cannot access AT&T network settings on my phone app or view the devices connected. An error comes up.

I tried both Cloudflare and Google DNS already. Confirmed it is not the issue. If I used my mobile hotspot, it works.

Not sure if anyone has encountered this issue before but thankful for any input.

Note: I have restarted the router but the same issues persist. I use a Mac.

Comment: Try using Cloudflare or Google's DNS

Comment: What happens when you try another network? What error message do you see?

Comment: I tried both cloudflare and google DNS already. Confirmed it is not the issue. If I used my mobile hotspot, it works

Comment: What happens if you run `ping github.com` ? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)